# jQuery Selector From Table

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a table like below:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>james</td>
    <td>sawyer</td>
    <td><button id="getVal">Get</button></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>kate</td>
    <td>deluna</td>
    <td><button id="getVal">Get</button></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>tupac</td>
    <td>shakur</td>
    <td><button id="getVal">Get</button></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

I want to click 'Get' button then get all td value in tr. I try this code but it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#getVal').click(function () {            
         var name    = $(this).find('td:first');
         var surname = $(this).find('td:second');
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can i do that? Please help me!

Comment: You can't have the same `id` on multiple buttons

Comment: use class instead of id to identify the button. Otherwise it will only ever work on the first button because you can't have duplicated ids. And you can't do find inside "this" because "this" is the button and the td elements aren't inside it. Instead get the closest tr to the button and then find all td elements within _that_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same `id` multiple times. Give them a `class` instead.

It would change to this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>james</td>
    <td>sawyer</td>
    <td><button class="getVal">Get</button></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>kate</td>
    <td>deluna</td>
    <td><button class="getVal">Get</button></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>tupac</td>
    <td>shakur</td>
    <td><button class="getVal">Get</button></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

As long as you know for sure it are always the first and second `<td>` you can use the following jQuery (still feels hacky).

```
$('.getVal').click(function () {            
  var name    = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first').text();
  var surname = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
  console.log(name);
  console.log(surname);
});
```

A working JSFiddle [can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/yt5bro7z/)

Answer (score 0):

Do this way,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>james</td>
        <td>sawyer</td>
        <td><button class="get_button">Get</button></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>kate</td>
        <td>deluna</td>
        <td><button class="get_button">Get</button></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>tupac</td>
        <td>shakur</td>
        <td><button class="get_button">Get</button></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

And then select your td based on class, like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.get_button').click(function () {            
            var name    = $(this).find('td:first');
            var surname = $(this).find('td:second');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this one
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.getVal').click(function () {  
         var name    = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
     var surname = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
     
    alert(name);
    alert(surname)
         
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>james</td>
    <td>sawyer</td>
    <td><button class="getVal">Get</button></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>kate</td>
    <td>deluna</td>
    <td><button class="getVal">Get</button></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>tupac</td>
    <td>shakur</td>
    <td><button class="getVal">Get</button></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i want only clicked button's line td value. this is show all value man.